# how to validate username when creating new user in angular?

Tags: angular, validation, email

We need to follow standard email practice while creating new user.
User name
Uppercase and lowercase letters in English (A-Z, a-z)
Digits from 0 to 9
Special characters such as ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { |  ( ) , : ; < > @ [ \ ]
@ symbol must be there
after @ symbol allow only
Uppercase and lowercase letters in English (A-Z, a-z)
Digits from 0 to 9
A hyphen (-)
A period (.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in email validator
https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: can we take pattern in ts file and use it in different components for  email validations?if yes so pls tell me the steps